# Google Appengine Android gradle task

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, groovy

I have following task in Project `build.gradle` file of Android Studio to test Google Cloud Endpoint. I want to run `backend:appengineRun` task in `daemon` mode so it allows the gradle process to continue.

Project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task runTestsInLocalServer {
    dependsOn = ['runLocalServer', 'runAndroidTests', 'haltLocalServer']
}

task runAppEngine (dependsOn: ":backend:appengineRun") {
        project(":backend").afterEvaluate { backend ->
            backend.extensions.appengine.daemon = true
        }
        doLast {
            println "started the server!"
        }
    }

task runAndroidTests {
    shouldRunAfter 'runAppEngine'
    dependsOn ':app:connectedCheck'
    doLast {
        println "Testing finished..."
    }
}

task haltLocalServer {
    shouldRunAfter 'runAndroidTests'
    dependsOn ':backend:appengineStop'
    doLast {
        println "Server stopped..."
    }
}
```

App level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId 'com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free'
            dimension "default"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId 'com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid'
            dimension "default"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    freeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'

    implementation project(':JokeProvider')
    implementation project(':jokedisplay')

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is the Error that I get:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not set unknown property 'daemon' for object of type com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.setMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.setProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension_Decorated.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:484)
```

Comment: It seems like you are missing some dependence or import. Can you put the full code?

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow this [doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin).

I think you have to add some lines to your code (Project-level build.gradle):

```
     repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()   <---
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
   ...
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.59'   <---
  }
```